# url rewriting pattern is not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

my current application is using codeigniter, where a method will output will deliver javascript code which can be included in one of my other domain site.

my requested url will be like

http://domain.com/widget/ID.js

will be re-written as

http://domain.com/home/widget/ID

**here is my code but not working**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^widget/([a-z0-9-]+)\.js/$ home/widget/$1 [NC]
```

can any one help me with that thank you.

Comment: You have the rule backwards.

Comment: ok , can you help me with a example.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^home/widget/([a-z0-9-]+)$ /widget/$1.js [NC,L]`

Comment: sorry its not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is it giving you a 404? Did you use the `L` flag at the end?

Comment: yes i used l , i am getting 404

Comment: Are you placing the rule below the first occurence of `RewriteEngine on`? (I am asking because I have seen folks use more than one of those directives.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to rewrite /widget/ID.js to /home/widget/ID, then your original rule was correct (it was not backwards). It probably just requires some fine tuning. Assuming you can successfully hit the rewrite target URL on its own?

http://domain.com/home/widget/ID

Then I would try adding leading slashes to both your pattern and sub and removing the trailing slash in your pattern:

RewriteRule ^/widget/([a-z0-9-]+).js$ /home/widget/$1 [NC]

Also, make sure you've enabled the rewrite module:

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Comment: This is incorrect. The OP wants to access `/widget/something.js` by requesting `/home/widget/something`. So the rule used *is* backwards. Additionally, you never user leading slashes in rewrite patterns. Your answer shows no research, and appears to be a 'guess' - this is not helpful to the OP.

Comment: @MikeRockett. Thank you for the feedback and my apologies if I've misunderstood the question, though I feel the OP may be in a better position to make that call. I'm not sure how / why my answer shows no "research"? My answer was based purely on the requirements the OP has listed and made no assumptions. This is why I started my answer with "IF" as opposed to simply declaring the rule as being backwards. Could you please explain why you "never use leading slashes"? Thank you.

Comment: The OP stated that the URI "will be re-written as" `/home/widget/ID`, which is a clear intention of the requirement. Regarding the leading slash in the pattern, [this answer](/a/27120/26881) should clarify it for you.

Comment: @MikeRockett. we just interpreted this differently. "my requested url will be like" http://domain.com/widget/ID.js. I took this to mean the OP will request that URL. "will be re-written as" http://domain.com/home/widget/ID. I took this to mean the OP wants it rewritten to that URL. And even though my answer IS valid given that interpretation, I still began my answer with "IF". Its up to the OP to clarify which interpretation is correct instead of your assuming that yours is correct, down-voting mine and declaring it not helpful. Even if yours is correct, mine was helpful to clarify the issue.

Comment: And your "this answer" link comes up as 'Page not found'.

Comment: Understood. I 'jumped the gun', as it were, for one reason: there are so many answers popping up that show lack of research, and a lack of actually reading the question, and not much is being done to point it out. So I do apologise for that - no offence was meant. I assume the question for that answer was deleted - was working when I posted it.